# Unique value per day

Tags: mysql, database

i am looking how to have unique value per day, here an exemple:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS calls (
  id int(11) default NULL,
  calldate datetime default NULL,
  dst varchar(80) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO calls (id, calldate, dst) VALUES
(1, '2014-05-03 20:45:43', '22561037352'),
(2, '2014-05-04 20:07:49', '22561037352'),
(3, '2014-05-04 13:16:14', '22561037352'),
(4, '2014-05-04 20:08:58', '22560991034'),
(5, '2014-05-04 16:06:02', '22560991034'),
(6, '2014-05-04 20:22:19', '22560842218');
```

[sqlfiddle: Copy and paste to test](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

we have two number coming two times per day `22561037352` & `22560991034`, i want to show unique number per day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM (SELECT DATE (calldate) as calldate, dst FROM calls) t
```

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/84076/11

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT (calldate,'%Y-%m-%d') calldate, dst
FROM calls
```

Answer (score 0):

First call to the number for the day

```
SELECT *
FROM calls c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'a'
                  FROM calls c2
                  WHERE c2.dst = c.dst
                  AND DATE_FORMAT(c2.calldate,'%d/%m/%Y') = DATE_FORMAT(c.calldate,'%d/%m/%Y')
                  AND c2.calldate < c.calldate
                 )
```